# flexSlider add class to slide

Tags: javascript, addclass, flexslider

I have a flexSlider using it as a carousel showing three slides, with a total of 7 slides. I have setup my outer div wrapping the flexslider so that the center slide is centered in the screen and stays the same size as you resize the screen, and the outer slides stay the same size, but show from 0% to 100% of the slide depending on the size of the screen. So as you resize the screen the two outside slides disappear off the screen. This works fine.

I would like to add a class to the first and third (visible) slides that would set the opacity for those slides, and as the carousel transitions to the next slide then I would want to remove the class from the old 1 & 3 slides and place it on the new 1 & 3 slides. This would create the effect that the center (slide 2) is the focus, but you get a preview, post view of the slide as it moves across the screen.

Thank you in advance, code below.

```
<style type="text/css">
#outer1{
    width:1764px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#inner1{
    width:1800px;
    position:relative;
}
.SlideContent {
    Margin:0 5px;
}
.inactive-slide{
    zoom:1;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.2;
    -moz-opacity:0.2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    opacity: 0.2;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        easing: "swing",
        animationLoop: true,
        smoothHeight: false, 
        startAt: 0,
        slideshow: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        animationSpeed: 600,
        randomize: false,
        useCSS: true,
        pauseOnAction: true,
        pauseOnHover: true, 
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: true,
        prevText: "Previous",
        nextText: "Next",
        itemWidth: 588,
        itemMargin: 10,
        minItems: 3,
        maxItems: 3

    });
    var x = window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth||0;
    var ILT = (x - 1764)/2;
    $('#outer1').css({'left':ILT + 'px'});
  });
window.onresize = function ()
{
    var x = window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth||0;
    var ILT = (x - 1764)/2;
    $('#outer1').css({'left':ILT + 'px'});
 };
</script>
.......
<div id="outer1">
    <div id="inner1" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <div class="SlideContent"><img src="image1.jpg" /></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="SlideContent"><img src="image2.jpg" /></div>
        </li>
        <li>
         <div class="SlideContent"><img src="image3.jpg" /></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="SlideContent"><img src="image4.jpg"  /></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="SlideContent"><img src="image5.jpg" /></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="SlideContent"><img src="image6.jpg" /></div>
        </li>
            <li>
          <div class="SlideContent"><img src="image7.jpg" /></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your slides to be responsive (as you scale your browser window) You'll need to set your widths and margins to be percentages.

Comment: thank you, and yes I will add code that will change the size of the outer div that will allow the flexslider to be responsive, but I would like to get the opacity working, any suggestions?

Comment: You could use the jQuery method, `.fadeTo()` or `.animate()` http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/